# "Frictionless payments" using the Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-credits

For a game we are developing for facebook we would like to use a feature facebook calls "**Frictionless payments**" which is described in the developber blog of facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/458/

It allows to let the user buy items in your application without confirming, if the item is worth up to 30 facebook credits and the user got this credits in his account available.

The code example in the blog is not working and the links to the documentation and a link to apply for this new feature are dead. I couldn't find more documentation about this feature but we know it exists as we saw it in other games.

So my question is, how can we implement this feature? Do we need to apply somewhere to use this feature and if yes, where can we do that.

Answer (score 1):

I recall you need Facebook to enable this for your app/game. You have to email them and specifically ask for it. Then frictionless payments automatically happen.

Comment: When OP asked this question it wasn't automatic

Answer (score 0):

**Reference:** Facebook Credits API Documentation

May be you could use facebook `pay dialog`

As for your question on where to apply, [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/build/) is a tutorial on how to `register a company` information and payment methods.

Look at [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/pay/#usage_notes) for usage of `pay dialog`

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/pay/#js_example) is a `javascript example` for the same

Hope this helps

Comment: I have read the credits documentation available and there is no information about the **"Frictionless payments"** we want to implement. The simple **pay dialog** always results in a popup where the user has to confirm the transaction, which is not the behavior we need.